# Dockerfile doesn't run the CMD if the ENTRYPOINT isn't finished

Tags: postgresql, docker, cmd, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to run a Dockerfile that run PostgreSQL and then add some tables to it.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

MAINTAINER agomez@ikerlan.es

USER postgres
ADD ./backup.sql /backup.sql
ADD ./deploy/import_database.sh /import_database.sh

USER root
RUN chmod +x /import_database.sh

USER postgres

ENTRYPOINT ./docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
CMD ./import_database.sh
```

The entrypoint doesn't finish becouse it runs the postgres server.
How can I run the CMD for example, after 20 seconds of running the ENTRYPOINT, but without finishing the ENTRYPOINT?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` work. I'd recommend reading https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact and checking the chart for a better understanding of how the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` interact with each other.

That said, if all you want to do is import a SQL file or run a script at runtime, the official PostgreSQL image already has you covered. See https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image for information on how to do this.

An example in the case of your `Dockerfile` (if you just wanted to import the SQL file) would be to do something like:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
ADD ./backup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql
```

When starting a container from the image build on this `Dockerfile`, the default `ENTRYPOINT` script will start a temporary PostgreSQL instance, wait for it to be ready, import your data, and then restart to serve connections.

Comment: Really thanks!! It works perfect for me :) , I would read it how `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` works together.